# Sharepoint Validation Settings and Formulas

Tags: sharepoint-designer

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Resolved Exception])=TRUE,Resolved<>"Yes"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Ethics Exception])=TRUE,Ethics<>"Yes"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Data Privacy Practices Exception])=TRUE,[Data Privacy Practices]<>"Yes"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Preparation Exception])=TRUE,[Preparation Review]<>"Yes"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Acknowledgement Exception])=TRUE,[Acknowledgement]<>"Yes"),FALSE,TRUE)))))
```

This is a working formula I used under List Settings/Validate Settings to validate if dropdown **resolved** value is <> "Yes" then **resolved exception** must not <> empty and so on. My  problem is, I don't know how to add an additional validation if one of these dropdowns Resolved, Ethics, Data Privacy Practices, Preparation Review, ***OR*** Acknowledgement <> Yes
then a message should show telling user - FINAL CERTIFICATION DROPDOWN must be = "No". I think I need to use an "OR" formula but just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(OR(
        OR(
            OR(
                OR(AND(ISBLANK([Resolved Exception])=FALSE,[Resolved] = "Yes")
                    ,AND(ISBLANK([Ethics Exception])=FALSE,[Ethics]="Yes")
                  )
                ,AND(ISBLANK([Data Privacy Practices Exception])=FALSE,[Data Privacy Practices]="Yes")
              ) 
            ,AND(ISBLANK([Preparation Exception])=FALSE,[Preparation Review]="Yes")
         )
         ,AND(ISBLANK([Acknowledgement Exception])=FALSE,[Acknowledgement]="Yes")
      )
    ,FALSE
    ,TRUE
   )
```

I removed the final certification validation requirement so this is my final formula but Sharepoint doesn't like it. Error message like it is more than the required characters so do you have a sample jquery to mimic this formula?

```
= AND(NOT(AND(ISBLANK([Resolved Exception]),Resolved<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([Ethics Exception]),Ethics<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([DPP Exception]),[Data Privacy Practices]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([P/R Exception]),[Preparation/Review]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([ACK Exception]),Acknowledgement<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([CS Exception]),[Circulation Statistics]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([UV Exception]),[Unusual Variances]<>"Yes")),
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([P&S Exception]),[Pilferage & Shrinkage]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([SC Exception]),[Single Copy Returns]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([AA Exception]),[Adjustments Accuracy]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([PR Exception]),[Payroll Review]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([GL Exception]),[General Ledger]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([RESP Exception]),Responsibility<>"Yes")))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([UV Exception]),[Unusual Variances]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([ELI Exception]),[Expense Line Item]<>"Yes"))
)
```

Comment: It should be checking not equal to yes so s it === or != operator? and How can I add this formula to my present formula?

Comment: I have updated it according to your present formula.

Comment: I cannot go this formula route anymore due to the limitation of up to 7 IF statements only so I have to try jquery.

Comment: As per your question, here is only 1 IF statement in updated answer. Any ways, move with jquery

Comment: I have tried it. It is not showing me any error.

Comment: Are you trying it using sharepoint designer?

Comment: which one is not giving you an error? your IF formula or my AND formula? I tried your IF formula, it did not validate choosing either = "Yes" or <> "Yes" for the dropdown

Comment: Both are not giving me error. IF formula will validate if one from all column having "Yes" from drop down and related exception is blank. Add If formula. Try to set DPP Exception is blank and Data Privacy Practices = "Yes". You will get message with validation formula. Please make sure, change columns name in formula as per your list columns.